# Can we automate updating the chef node attributes?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a node with the following json in chef nodes:

```
 {
  "name": "app-node-01",
  "chef_environment": "dev",
  "run_list": [
  "recipe[hello-world]"
],
  "normal": {
    "app_version": "1.0.0",
    "tags": [

    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to look for a way to manage this json config in github and when there is a change in the version of `app_version`, I update the json file in github and update the version to `1.0.1` and run a command like `knife node edit -c <json file from github> app-node-01` the command will go over the json file and update the node in chef? is this possible?

I tried the command in my local but it opened the VI editor for me to edit.

I dont want to do manual edits as I am trying to look for a way to manage this also in github just like any other chef artifact (data bags, environment files, cookbooks etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with other Chef artifacts, nodes can also be updated from file using the `from file` argument.

Instead of `knife node edit`, you need to run:

```
knife node from file PATH_TO_JSON_FILE
```